# cant figure out jquery .show() and .hide(), im a noob very confused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project, and cant figure out how to hide my welcome2 and welcome2-0 html code, then once the button is pressed show that information. im new with jquery, and am really confused tried looking this stuff up and still have little idea on how to fix this issue. i appreciate any help or input guys, sorry if anything poorly formatted.

```js
var name ;
var nameFormat=true;
function submission() {
    var name = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    if (name.length > 0) {
        alert("Welcome "+name);
        $("#name").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#welcome").fadeOut(1000);
        
       
       
       
        
    }
    else{
        nameFormat==false;
        alert("Please enter the name again");
    }

   

}
```

```css
#welcome{
    top:30px;
    left: 30px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    background: blue;
    padding: 25px;
  
}

#name{
 
    top:30px;
    left: 500px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    background: blue;
    border: 25px solid blue;
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
#welcome2{
    position: relative;
    top:30px;
    left: 30px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    background: blue;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
HTML


<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
 <title>Welcome!</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/styles1.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<p>
<body>
<div id="welcome"><b>Welcome to the Myanmar Trivia Quiz</b><br> please enter your name and click on "Begin Quiz" to start</div>
<div id ="name"><b>Name:</b> 

<input type="text" id="textbox">
<button id=”myButton” type="button" onclick="submission()" >submit</button>
</p>



<div id="welcome2">Myanmar Trivia Quiz </div>
<div id="welcome2-0">Test your Demographic Knowledge<br>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</div>

</div>


</body>
<script src="includes/project.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: `var nameFormat=True;` is, from the code you've posted, an `Uncaught ReferenceError` since you've not defined `True` (note that JavaScript is case-sensitive and Boolean `true` is lower-case, whereas `True`, as you wrote, is a potentially-confusing variable name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things:

- Your HTML was malformed
- You need to set `display: none` on the css
  for what you want to be hidden at the start
- You need to call fadeIn
  (or show) on the element AFTER fadeOut (or hide) has finished, you
  can do that using promises and the fadeIn callback function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

```js
var name ;
var nameFormat=true;
function submission() {
    var name = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    if (name.length > 0) {
        alert("Welcome "+name);
        fadeOutWelcome().then(() => fadeInWelcome());
    }
    else{
        nameFormat==false;
        alert("Please enter the name again");
    }
}

const fadeOutWelcome = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
      $("#name").fadeOut(1000, () => resolve());
      $("#welcome").fadeOut(1000);
  });
}

const fadeInWelcome = () => {
  $("#welcome2").fadeIn(1000);
  $("#welcome2-0").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

```css
#welcome{
    top:30px;
    left: 30px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    background: blue;
    padding: 25px;
  
}

#name{
 
    top:30px;
    left: 500px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    background: blue;
    border: 25px solid blue;
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
#welcome2{
  display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:30px;
    left: 30px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    background: blue;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
HTML


<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
 <title>Welcome!</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/styles1.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<p>
<body>
<div id="welcome"><b>Welcome to the Myanmar Trivia Quiz</b><br> please enter your name and click on "Begin Quiz" to start</div>
<div id ="name"><b>Name:</b> 

<input type="text" id="textbox">
<button id=”myButton” type="button" onclick="submission()" >submit</button>
</p>
</div>


<div id="welcome2">Myanmar Trivia Quiz
<div id="welcome2-0">Test your Demographic Knowledge<br>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</div>

</div>


</body>
<script src="includes/project.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro, ill give you the answer. also thanks again for some additional resources to learn more about this stuff. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

Javascript is case-sensitive, so true is a reserved word, True is not. So instead of var nameFormat=True , you should do: var nameFormat= true .

Then, you're saying you want to hide welcome2 and welcome2-0 divs, but in your javascript code you're not doing this. If you want do this, do the following:

```
$("#welcome2").hide();
$("#welcome2-0").hide();
// or
$("#welcome2").fadeOut(100);
$("#welcome2-0").fadeOut(100);
```

There is another issue in your else block: you're doing nameFormat==false , which is just comparing if nameFormat is false. If you want to assign false to nameFormat variable, do this:

```
nameFormat = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) at the beginning of your javascript code (so that it executes at the very beginning) which would hide those 2 divs.

Then when the button is pressed, use [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to show those 2 divs again.

Also, where you had `nameFormat == false;`, you need to change that to `nameFormat = false;`. `==` is the comparison operator, so it would look at that and say *"Oh nameFormat is not false"*, and move on. If you wanted to make nameFormat be false (which I assume you did), you must use the assignment operator (which is `=`)

```js
var name;
var nameFormat = true;
$("#welcome2").hide();
$("#welcome2-0").hide();


function submission() {
  var name = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
  if (name.length > 0) {
    alert("Welcome " + name);
    $("#name").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#welcome").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#welcome2").show();
    $("#welcome2-0").show();

  } else {
    nameFormat == false;
    alert("Please enter the name again");
  }



}
```

```css
#welcome {
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  color: antiquewhite;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: blue;
  padding: 25px;
}

#name {
  top: 30px;
  left: 500px;
  color: antiquewhite;
  background: blue;
  border: 25px solid blue;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#welcome2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  color: antiquewhite;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: blue;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
HTML


<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Welcome!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/styles1.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<p>

  <body>
    <div id="welcome"><b>Welcome to the Myanmar Trivia Quiz</b><br> please enter your name and click on "Begin Quiz" to start</div>
    <div id="name"><b>Name:</b>

      <input type="text" id="textbox">
      <button id=”myButton” type="button" onclick="submission()">submit</button>
</div>



<div id="welcome2">Myanmar Trivia Quiz </div>
<div id="welcome2-0">Test your Demographic Knowledge<br>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</div>

</div>


</body>
<script src="includes/project.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are trying to do, it's simply as:

```
var name;
var nameFormat=true;
function submission() {
    name = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    if (name.length > 0) {
        alert("Welcome "+name);
        $("#name").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#welcome").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#welcome2").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#welcome2-0").fadeIn(1000);        
    }
    else{
        nameFormat=false;
        alert("Please enter the name again");
    }
}
```

Since you showed up in your code `fadeOut`, I made my answer with that. Otherwise you can replace fadeIn with show.

About your CSS code, try to set `display: none;` for those elements that should be hidden when the page loads.

For more info look at:

http://api.jquery.com/show/